# How to use a .11ty.js file?

Tags: eleventy

I have a `sample.11ty.js` file, containing the following code:

```
module.exports = "<p>sample</p>";
```

In a `njk` layout file, I tried to include the above `sample.11ty.js` file like so:

```
{% include "components/sample.11ty.js" %}
```

The `sample` paragraph does not display, but there is the following error in the console:

```
Reference Error: module is not defined
```

> How can I include a `.11ty.js` file in a `njk` template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [official Nunjucks documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#include):

> **an include is not a pre-processor** that pulls the included template code into the including template before rendering; instead, it fires off a separate render of the included template, and the results of that render are included.

So it seems that trying to pre-process javascript in a Nunjucks include file is deemed to fail.

---

However, the following works:

In a `njk` layout file, use the following frontmatter:

`---
layout: layouts/sample.11ty.js
---`

And in `layouts/sample.11ty.js`, use a javascript class like so:

```
class Sample {
data() {
return {
  name: "Eleventy"
  };
}
render(data){
    return data.content;
  }
}

module.exports = Sample;
```